# Given text can not be applied to TextView when TextView parameters are changed

Tags: android, kotlin

So I've made an extension to implement Precomputed Text in a TextView.

I've been getting errors though ever since I've migrated to Material Components Theme.

Here's the code below.

I've also tried migrating all TextViews, and AppCompatTextViews to MaterialTextView. Yet the issue is still occurring.

```
fun AppCompatTextView.setTextFuture(string: String?) {
    val precomputedText =
        PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture(
            string ?: "",
            TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(this),
            null
        )

    textMetricsParamsCompat = precomputedText.get().params
    setTextFuture(precomputedText)
    text = string

}

fun AppCompatTextView.setTextFuture(charSequence: CharSequence?) {
    val precomputedText =
        PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture(
            charSequence ?: "",
            TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(this),
            null
        )

    textMetricsParamsCompat = precomputedText.get().params
    setTextFuture(precomputedText)
    text = charSequence
}

fun AppCompatTextView.setTextFuture(stringResId: Int) {
    val string = context.getString(stringResId)

    val precomputedText =
        PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture(
            string,
            TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(this),
            null
        )

    textMetricsParamsCompat = precomputedText.get().params
    setTextFuture(precomputedText)
    text = string
}
```

The errors have been the following.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Given text can not be applied to TextView.
androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat.setPrecomputedText (TextViewCompat.java:891)
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.onMeasure (AppCompatTextView.java:550)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:24953)
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
PrecomputedText's Parameters don't match the parameters of this TextView.Consider using setTextMetricsParams(precomputedText.getParams()) to override the settings of this TextView: PrecomputedText: {textSize=49.0, textScaleX=1.0, textSkewX=0.0, letterSpacing=0.03125, textLocale=[en_GB], typeface=android.graphics.Typeface@5e608edd, variationSettings=null, elegantTextHeight=false, textDir=android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@eb941bf, breakStrategy=1, hyphenationFrequency=0}TextView: {textSize=49.0, textScaleX=1.0, textSkewX=0.0, letterSpacing=0.03125, textLocale=[en_GB], typeface=android.graphics.Typeface@5e608edd, variationSettings=null, elegantTextHeight=false, textDir=android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@eb941bf, breakStrategy=1, hyphenationFrequency=0}
android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6724)
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
PrecomputedText's Parameters don't match the parameters of this TextView.Consider using setTextMetricsParams(precomputedText.getParams()) to override the settings of this TextView: PrecomputedText: {textSize=70.0, textScaleX=1.0, textSkewX=0.0, letterSpacing=0.03125, textLocale=[en_CA], typeface=android.graphics.Typeface@ab2ab1bb, variationSettings=null, elegantTextHeight=false, textDir=android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@34fe469, breakStrategy=1, hyphenationFrequency=0}TextView: {textSize=70.0, textScaleX=1.0, textSkewX=0.0, letterSpacing=0.03125, textLocale=[en_CA], typeface=android.graphics.Typeface@ab2ab1bb, variationSettings=null, elegantTextHeight=false, textDir=android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$TextDirectionHeuristicInternal@34fe469, breakStrategy=1, hyphenationFrequency=0}
android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6731)
```

Some of my TextViews have these properties

```
android:ellipSize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"

isSelected = true
```

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this. Ar you using Theme.MaterialComponents.Light ?

from 
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05"
 ?

Comment: Have you tried changing `textMetricsParamsCompat` to `textMetricsParams`? :)

Comment: @VytautasBerankis I'm using 1.1.0-beta02 mean while we'll release an update today and observe rc02. The error is only happening to specific devices though, specifically Samsung and those that are running Android 9

Comment: Worth noting: calling `precomputedText.get()` like this is defeating the entire purpose of doing this.  You should check the documentation for `Future.get`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing the same error, also using Material Components and only on samsung devices

Comment: @Bobbobbington You can check Bahman's answer. Since mine was in a RecyclerView I checked if the Activity was still alive before precomputing the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> all `TextView` layout properties must be set before creating the Params
>   object. If they are changed during the precomputation, **this can cause
>   a `IllegalArgumentException` when the precomputed value is consumed
>   during measure**, and doesn't reflect the TextView's current state.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/PrecomputedTextCompat

so its important when you call this method: `setTextFuture`